# Test Class for before insert and update trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am new to apex triggers and test. I want to learn how to test triggers. So here is my code can anyone write test class and explain me step by step

```
trigger PrimaryContactOnContact on Contact (before insert,before update) {

    // Variable Declaration
    set<id> iden = new set<id>();
    string contactId;
    List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();

    // Trigger Functionality
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) {

        for(Contact cont: Trigger.New) {

            if(cont.Primary_Contact__c == true) {

                iden.add(cont.AccountId);
                contactId = cont.id;
            }
        }
    }

    // Fetching the other Contact which has primary contact checked
    List<contact> cList = [select id, Primary_Contact__c from contact where accountid IN: iden AND Primary_Contact__c = true];

    // Unchecking the already checked primary contact
    if(cList.size() > 0) {

        for(Contact newClst: cList) {

            if(newClst.id != contactId) {

                newClst.Primary_Contact__c = false;
                conList.add(newClst);
            }
        }
    }   
    update conList;    
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
public class PrimaryContactOnContact_Test {

    public static testmethod void PrimaryContactTest()
    {

        Company__c com = new Company__c();
        com.Name = 'TestForPrimaryContact';
        com.Phone__c = '832648276';
        com.Manager__c = 'prince';
        com.E_Mail__c = 'prince@example.com';
        insert com;
        Account acc = new Account(Name='TestPrimayContact', CurrencyIsoCode = 'AUD',Company__c = com.Id, Company_ID__c= '12345', Partner__c='Direct', Industry = 'Aviation', Type='Prospect', Region__c='Asia', c2g__CODAAccountTradingCurrency__c = 'EUR');
        insert acc;
        Account ac1 = [select id from Account where name = 'TestPrimayContact'];
        List<Contact> con = new List<Contact>{new Contact (CurrencyIsoCode = 'AUD', LastName = 'xxxx', Account = ac1, Primary_Contact__c = true),
                                              new Contact (CurrencyIsoCode = 'AUD', LastName = 'yyyy', Account = ac1, Primary_Contact__c = false)           
                                             };
        insert con;
        List<Contact> lstCont = new List<Contact>();
        Contact con1 = new Contact();
        if(con1.LastName == 'xxxx'){
            con1.Primary_Contact__c = false;
            lstCont.add(con1);
        }
        update lstCont;                
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a good start for writing test classes https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests

Comment: I have written test class but it only cover 73% @VigneshwaranG

Comment: Please edit the question and add the test class and mention the lines which are not covered by the test class. Am pretty much sure, you will get lots of help in right direction if you provide as much details as possible.

Comment: testclass is added @VigneshwaranG

Answer (score 1):

A good test method for your class will be:

```
public static testmethod void PrimaryContactTest() {
    Account acc = new Account(Name = 'TestPrimayContact', CurrencyIsoCode = 'AUD', Company__c = com.Id, Company_ID__c = '12345', Partner__c = 'Direct', Industry = 'Aviation', Type = 'Prospect', Region__c = 'Asia', c2g__CODAAccountTradingCurrency__c = 'EUR');
    insert acc;
    List < Contact > con = new List < Contact > {
        new Contact(CurrencyIsoCode = 'AUD', LastName = 'xxxx', AccountId = acc.Id, Primary_Contact__c = true),
        new Contact(CurrencyIsoCode = 'AUD', LastName = 'yyyy', AccountId = acc.Id, Primary_Contact__c = false)
    };
    insert con;

    Contact c = [select Id, Primary_Contact__c from Contact where LastName = 'xxxx'
    and Primary_Contact__c = false];
    c.Primary_Contact__c = true;
    update c;
}
```

Comment: it will not update or insert on company it should affect on contact. contact has a lookup to account and account has a lookup to company. My class doing, accound should have only one primary contact. @Santanu halder

Comment: My bad, I read Company as Contact. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This test class will help you to cover the trigger.

```
@isTest
public class PrimaryContactOnContact_Test {

    public static testmethod void PrimaryContactTest()
    {

        Company__c com = new Company__c();
        com.Name = 'TestForPrimaryContact';
        com.Phone__c = '832648276';
        com.Manager__c = 'prince';
        com.E_Mail__c = 'prince@example.com';
        insert com;
        Account acc = new Account(Name='TestPrimayContact', CurrencyIsoCode = 'AUD',Company__c = com.Id, Company_ID__c= '12345', Partner__c='Direct', Industry = 'Aviation', Type='Prospect', Region__c='Asia', c2g__CODAAccountTradingCurrency__c = 'EUR');
        insert acc;
        Account ac1 = [select id from Account where name = 'TestPrimayContact'];
        List<Contact> con = new List<Contact>{new Contact (CurrencyIsoCode = 'AUD', LastName = 'xxxx', Account = ac1, Primary_Contact__c = true),
                                              new Contact (CurrencyIsoCode = 'AUD', LastName = 'yyyy', Account = ac1, Primary_Contact__c = false)           
                                             };
        insert con;
        Contact con1 = new Contact(CurrencyIsoCode = 'AUD', LastName = 'zzzz', Account = ac1, Primary_Contact__c = true);
        insert con1;
        con1 = [select Primary_Contact__c From contact where LastName = 'xxxx'];
        con1.Primary_Contact__c = true;
        update con1;
    }
}
```